# Yql HTTP authorization

Tags: javascript, yql

I have a problem with using yql service in my JavaScript application. Service from which I want to extract information requires 
HTTP authentication. I do not know how to set yql to identify with a specific user name and password.
I read here: http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql_url.html but I do not see anywhere how to transmit user name and password needed for 
HTTP authorization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with **execute** element.

> Better support for calling external Web services: Some Web services
>   use their own security and authentication mechanisms. Some also
>   require authentication headers to be set in the Web service request.
>   The execute element allows you to do both.
>   http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-execute-chapter.html#yql-execute-intro